# How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am getting following error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'tblUnit.Unit_DescFROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit]'. andthis one Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Part of code that is failing:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql As String
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbInventor.mdb"
    connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connetionString)

    connection.Open()
    sql = "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc" _
        & "FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit];"

    oledbAdapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
    oledbAdapter.Fill(ds)
        oledbAdapter.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1))
        Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Whet do you mean by `break my code` ??

Comment: change this "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc" to this "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc " /// missing space before FROM

Comment: you need a space after "Unit_Desc"

Comment: I know the error is due to missing space.  Just thought I would provide additional information of the error.  I've seen this error in EXCEL VBA which is very similar to Access VBA.  There are two different mode for a table.  One is CommandText and the other CommandTable.  To perform a query the table must be set to CommandText. Apparently the missing space is assuming the table is set to CommandTable.  It took me a long time in excel to figure out this confusing error message.

Comment: thank, i will try suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a space before `FROM` like this :

```
sql = "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc" _
    & " FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit];"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sql = "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc " _
    & "FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit];"
```

or

```
sql = "SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc" _
    & " FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit];"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an xml literal to format long or complex SQL however you like:

```
Dim sql = <sql>
        SELECT tblStocks.Stk_LinkUnit, tblUnit.Unit_Desc 
        FROM tblUnit INNER JOIN tblStocks ON 
                        tblUnit.[Unit_Control] = tblStocks.[Stk_LinkUnit]
        WHERE Foo=@p1 
            AND Bar=@p2
        </sql>.Value

Console.WriteLine(sql)
```

Be sure to include the `.Value`